# Comparing array elements and style.fontFamily

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, fonts

I'm working on developing a text font game where the user guesses the font displayed on the screen, however an issue arises when I try to compare the style.familyFont of the text clicked and the corresponding array element font.

After doing some tests, it appears that the console prints out false when comparing the style.familyFont === corresponding array element, only when the style.familyFont contains a font that contains a space.
Example of console displaying the comparisons :

Courier New == "Courier New"   false

Times New Roman == "Times New Roman" false

Arial == Arial true

Calibri == Calibri true

Papyrus == Papyrus true

Tahoma == Tahoma true

Judging by the console, when the code assigns pickedOption = this.style.fontFamily, pickedOption obtains character quotes for fonts that contain a space and thus comparison results in false.

Is there a way I can handle this issue?

```js
var fonts = ["Arial", "Calibri", "Tahoma", "Papyrus", "Times New Roman", "Courier New"];
var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
var winningFont = generateWinningFont();
var fontDisplay = document.getElementById("fontDisplay");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
fontDisplay.textContent = "Fargo";
fontDisplay.style.fontFamily = fonts[winningFont];
console.log(fonts[winningFont]);
console.log(winningFont);
setupOptions();

function generateWinningFont()
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length);
}

reset.addEventListener("click", function()
{
 winningFont = generateWinningFont();
 fontDisplay.textContent = "Fargo";
 fontDisplay.style.fontFamily = fonts[winningFont];
 setupOptions();
});

function setupOptions()
{
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
 {
  options[i].style.fontFamily = fonts[i];
  options[i].textContent = fonts[i];
  options[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   var pickedOption = this.style.fontFamily;
   console.log(pickedOption);
   console.log(pickedOption == fonts[winningFont]);
   if(pickedOption == fonts[winningFont])
   {
    message.textContent = "Correct!";
   }
   else 
   {
    message.textContent = "Try Again!";
   }
  });
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Text Font Game</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>The Great 
  <br>
  <span id="fontDisplay"></span> 
  <br>
  Text Font Game
 </h1>
 
 <div id="stripe">
  <button id="reset">New Font</button>
  <span id="message"></span>
  <button class="mode">Easy</button>
  <button class="mode selected">Hard</button>
 </div>

 <div id="container">
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="textGame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test you code but from looking at it I see few things that might be a problem here.

1. You are using element.style.fontFamily to get styles which are not applied by js thus you are I'm 100% sure getting empty string
2. You use '==' instead of '===' - This way you are checking for both value and value type

As for the first problem. You should use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('fontFamily')
```

This way you are actually getting styles applied by css. Or you can use still use .style.fontFamily but then you will have to set font family via inline style of with JS which is the same.

docs --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle